# DAX Running Total with Buckets

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm newish to Power BI/DAX, and I'm having trouble getting a running total to work the way I need. Assume the following table for data:

```
User    month   sales
UserA   1/1/2019    1
UserB   1/1/2019    3
UserC   1/1/2019    2
UserA   2/1/2019    1
UserB   2/1/2019    3
UserC   2/1/2019    2
UserA   3/1/2019    1
UserB   3/1/2019    3
UserC   3/1/2019    2
```

I've been looking around and I've found the following formula gives me a good running total the way I need:

```
AllSales = 
calculate(
    sum('table'[Sales]),
    filter(
        all ('table'),
        'table'[date] <= max ('table'[date])
        )
)
```

--

```
Total   6   12  18  18
```

The problem comes when I want to see this in matrix form with the users breaking out into buckets. When I do this, the number of sales is the same for each user:

```
UserA   6   12  18  18
UserB   6   12  18  18
UserC   6   12  18  18
Total   6   12  18  18
```

My desired outcome would look like this:

```
UserA   1   2   3   3
UserB   3   6   9   9
UserC   2   4   6   6
Total   6   12  18  18
```

I believe I understand why the ALL function is causing this, but I don't know how to tweak it or which function to switch to in order to resolve this issue. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying ALL to the entire table, apply it only to the column you need:

```
AllSales =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'table'[Sales] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'table'[date] ), 'table'[date] <= MAX ( 'table'[date] ) )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Once again, seems so obvious now that I see it.