# Power BI - How to get running total and adding it along to your set of data

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I have a sample data set in Power BI. I was wondering if I could get a running total for Type A and adding it along with the original data?

I have an example.

**Here is the data.**

[image: table1]

I created a matrix table in Power BI to view the data like this:

[image: table2]

**I was wondering if I could add the running total to the same matrix table, as well as having a different value for "Type". Something like this.**

[image: table4]

Please let me know if this is possible. I know how to get the running total using the CALCULATE function but I don't know how to add it to the table along with the original data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DAX Running Total with Buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547303/dax-running-total-with-buckets)

Comment: See this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226792/how-to-calculate-cumulative-total-and-in-dax

Comment: @AlexisOlson what about getting a running total for a certain "type" instead of everything?

Comment: That's what the first link is about.

Comment: @AlexisOlson the first link doesn't say much besides instead of applying ALL, apply only the columns you need. Which doesn't show how?

Comment: Your question is nearly identical. Just different column names.

Comment: @AlexisOlson yes, it's identical. But I'm asking based on a column, as well as a certain row. I want to get a running total based of the column "type", but only for type A (image above). I don't know if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can either tell it what row context to ignore:

```
RunningCount =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[Count] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Table1[Date] ),
        Table1[Date] <= MAX ( Table1[Date] )
    )

)
```

or you can tell it which row context to keep (removing all other context):

```
RunningCount =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[Count] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Type] ),
        Table1[Date] <= MAX ( Table1[Date] )
    )
)
```

These should give the same result in this case. I prefer the latter for this sort of thing in general since you're specifying what you're grouping over rather than what you don't want to keep in your grouping.