# Self-reference a column in DAX or Power Query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am looking to create column D of the table below in power query or DAX. You can see the excel formula in the cell. I need to add columns from the current row and add a previously calculated row above.  The column is self-referencing. I am stuck and do not know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Picture of Excel Data]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recursively self-reference a column in DAX. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766022/recursion-in-dax) for more detail on that.

That said, just like the examples linked in that post (also below), you don't really need recursion for your purpose but rather a [cumulative total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60981088/power-bi-how-to-get-running-total-and-adding-it-along-to-your-set-of-data) of Production - Demand plus an initial inventory amount.

That is, something like this:

```
Projected Inv. =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[Production] ) - SUM ( Table1[Demand] ),
    FILTER ( Table1[Date], Table1[Date] <= MAX ( Table1[Date] ) )
) + 174408
```

---

[How to perform sum of previous cells of same column in PowerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257536/how-to-perform-sum-of-previous-cells-of-same-column-in-powerbi)

[DAX - formula referencing itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641059/dax-formula-referencing-itself)