# A circular dependency was detected in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

Below is my table.

| GName | Year | Opening Stock | InQty | initemvaluee | Opening Stock Value | Average Value | Average Value previous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bahria Town | 2,016 |  | 4,454 | 126,610,300 | - | 28,426 |  |
| Bahria Town | 2,017 | 868 | 6,379 | 166,903,972 | - | 23,031 | 28,426 |

in average i am using formula

```
Average Value =
VAR foropning =
    IF (
        [Opening Stock] = 0,
        ( ( [initemvaluee] ) / ( [inqtyy] + [Opening Stock] ) )
    )
VAR notforopning =
    IF (
        [Opening Stock] <> 0,
        ( ( [initemvaluee] + [Opening Stock Value] ) / ( [inqtyy] + [Opening Stock] ) )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( [Opening Stock] = 0, foropning, notforopning )
```

for opening stock value i just simple doing

`Opening Stock Value = [Opening Stock] * [Average Value previous]`
it gives error please help out of dependancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your calculation for `[Average Value previous]` depends on `[Average Value]` which in turn depends on `[Opening Stock Value]` which loops right back around to depending on `[Average Value previous]`.

Comment: Yes you right. i not getting how to get out this error.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to define your columns recursively. Unfortunately, DAX isn't well-suited for this but there might be workarounds. See here for a bit more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809941

Comment: I am just taking the average from 2 field initem value and then average of them for calulcating the out stock value for that year.
and when it is new year then i have to forward that balance that's why i am forwarding the closing balance into next field which is closing balance of last yeear. Which will become opening balance for current year.